# How to run my MEAN stack code while making lots of changes without having to restart `npm start`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, mean-stack

I'm running my MMEAN stack app (Mongoose, MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js) with `npm start`.  **But whenever I make a change in the code, I have to quit and restart `npm start` for the changes to show up on my web application.** This is getting annoying now because I am still building my app so I'm making lots of changes. So what can I do to run my MMEAN stack app in a smoother way?

This is the directory structure of my app, based on [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial):

```
HTML        views/
Angular.js  public/javascript/
Express.js  routes/
Node.js     app.js
Mongoose js models/, connected in app.js
Mongo db    connected in app.js
```

Comment: The answer will be different for different parts of your app. For an express change this probably isn't possible, for angular it should be (but I don't know how off-hand).

Comment: you can look into forever and PM2, both have auto-relaunch. if you use clustering, PM2 can even reload your server code with zero downtime, how cool is that?

Comment: dandavis, thanks. Can you elaborate your comment in an answer with the differences among, forever, PM2, and nodemon? Which is the best for me and why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a a lot of solutions for this problem.

For example, go and give [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) a try.
Install it globally with `npm install -g nodemon` and after that run your code with `nodemon yourscript.js`.
It will watch your js files and restart your app every time, when you change something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Nodemon, then I'd suggest downloading the clear-cache Chrome plugin as well:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en

It will clear your cache on demand (just adds a button to your chrome toolbar). Then you don't need to install the Reload npm.

However, I would suggest using the npm modules supervisor and reload (reload clears the cache for you, and supervisor is usually a bit faster).

https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload